# Getting a value from Javascript Async request and use it for further logic

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I want to get a value from the async javascript call and store the retuned value in a variable and then write some logic based on the value.

My Javascript file looks like this.

```
function getAjax() {
    let mycall;
    myCall = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.github.com/users",
        dataType: "json"
    })
    return myCall;
}
async function myBlur1() {
    const myret = await getAjax();
    // if(myret[0].login == "mojombo"){
    //     return true;
    // }
    // else {return false;}
    console.log(myret);
    return myret[0].login;
}
```

Now in my HTML I would like to call the myBlur1 function and store the return value and then outside the function call I would like to build logic based on the return value.

Here is my HTML file.

```
<body>
    <div id="message"></div>
    <script>
        let failed = false;
        (async () => {
            console.log("I am inside IIFE");
            let ret = await myBlur1();
            if(ret == "mojombo")
            {
                failed = true;
            }
        })();
        
        if(failed){
            console.log("I am ready.");
        }
        else {
            console.log("I am not yet ready.")
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I am always getting
I am inside IIFE
I am not yet ready. and after that the
return arrays from async call.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your result, you have to make the scope inside script tag compatible with step by step asynchronous operations. so put whole code inside script in async IIFE.

```
<body>
    <div id="message"></div>
    <script>
      (async () => {
        let failed = false;
        await (async () => {
            console.log("I am inside IIFE");
            let ret = await myBlur1();
            if(ret == "mojombo")
            {
                failed = true;
            }
        })();
        
        if(failed){
            console.log("I am ready.");
        }
        else {
            console.log("I am not yet ready.")
        }
     })();
    </script>
</body>
```

more simplified updated version(as we are already inside async function)

```
<body>
    <div id="message"></div>
    <script>
      (async () => {

        let failed = false;
        let ret = await myBlur1();

        if(ret == "mojombo") {
           failed = true;
        }

        if(failed){
            console.log("I am ready.");
        }
        else {
            console.log("I am not yet ready.")
        }
     })();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your logic inside IIFE. after "await myBlur1()" call, becuase it is a network call it will take some time and wait for the next tick to return the result.

```
<body>
    <div id="message"></div>
    <script>
        let failed = false;
        (async () => {
            console.log("I am inside IIFE");
            /*
                anything you want to do until the 
                result doesn't come from "myBlur1" 
                should be written here.
            */
            let ret = await myBlur1();
            /*
              your logic should be here, this will execute once 
              the result from "myBlur1" is available
            */
        })();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes. Absolutely. Just did that.